# Storing seriaized ArrayList in SharedPreferences - ArrayList is empty when retrieving

Tags: android, serialization, arraylist, sharedpreferences, deserialization

The below code is certainly not the best way of doing what I need to do but unfortunately I don't have much time to go back and change data structures / storage options etc. It will be cleaned up however. Anyway, the quality of the code isn't my problem, I digress.

When the user registers their account for the first time, they are given a ListView with multiple choice (check boxes). The selected items are stored in a SparseBooleanArray then converted to an ArrayList of Strings.

The names of the ListView items are coming from an SQLite database method called getStoreNames() which returns an ArrayList of Strings of the Store names.

I need to then get the Store objects associated with each store name. This is done in the for loop within the continue_button case. (Store store = db.returnStoreByName(storeName)... then adding each of those stores to an ArrayList of Stores.

I am then trying to store this ArrayList of stores in SharedPreferences. Because SPs doesn't support ArrayLists, the data is serialized. In the next Activity when I try to access the Store objects, I deserialize the shared preference object. However when I checked the size of the deserialized ArrayList, it is 0. I checked the arraylist size before I serialized it and put it into shared preferences and it was giving the correct size.

This leads me to believe that somewhere between serializing/deserializing or storing in/retrieving from shared prefs is where something is going wrong and the arraylist is being emptied.

Here is the first activity where the data is saved to shared prefs.

```
package com.mad.losesano2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class StoreListRegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener{

    ListView list_view;
    List<String> stores;
    DB db;
    ArrayList<String> users_stores;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    Button continue_button;
    ArrayList<Store> stores_objects = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store_list_register);

        list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        list_view.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        list_view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        list_view.setItemsCanFocus(false);

        continue_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
        continue_button.setOnClickListener(this);

        db = new DB(getApplicationContext());

        stores = db.getStoreNames();

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, stores);

        list_view.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        SparseBooleanArray a = list_view.getCheckedItemPositions();

        users_stores = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 0; i < stores.size(); i++){
            if(a.valueAt(i)){
                String store_name = list_view.getAdapter().getItem(a.keyAt(i)).toString();
                users_stores.add(store_name);
            }
        }

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.continue_button:

                sp = getSharedPreferences("storeList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                for (String storeName : users_stores) {
                    Store store = db.returnStoreByName(storeName);
                    stores_objects.add(store); 
                    Log.d("LoSeSANO", "Store name: " + store.getName());
                    try {
                        editor.putString("usersStores", ObjectSerializer.serialize(stores_objects));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                Log.d("LoSeSANO", "Size: " + stores_objects.size());

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, LoggedInActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code where I try to receive the SP object

```
package com.mad.losesano2;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LoggedInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ArrayList<Store> store_list;
    SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged_in);

        if (null == store_list) {
            store_list = new ArrayList<Store>();
        }

        sp = getSharedPreferences("storeList", MODE_PRIVATE);

        try {
            store_list = (ArrayList<Store>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sp.getString("usersStores", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<Store>())));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       Log.d("LoSeSANO", "Store name  at index 0: " + store_list.get(0).getName()); //store_list size = 0.
    }
}
```

Lastly, here is the ObjectSerializer class

```
package com.mad.losesano2;

/**
 * Created by oshau on 18/03/2018.
 */

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ObjectSerializer {

    public static String serialize(Serializable obj) throws IOException {
        if (obj == null) return "";
        ByteArrayOutputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serialObj);
        objStream.writeObject(obj);
        objStream.close();
        return encodeBytes(serialObj.toByteArray());
    }

    public static Object deserialize(String str) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) return null;
        ByteArrayInputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodeBytes(str));
        ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(serialObj);
        return objStream.readObject();
    }

    public static String encodeBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
            strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i]) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
        }

        return strBuf.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] decodeBytes(String str) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=2) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            bytes[i/2] = (byte) ((c - 'a') << 4);
            c = str.charAt(i+1);
            bytes[i/2] += (c - 'a');
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mad.losesano2/com.mad.losesano2.LoggedInActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

From this Logcat it's clear that your array size is `0` and you are trying to access index `0`.  Make sure you check array length before accessing its content.

May be you are getting crash for this line

```
 Log.d("LoSeSANO", "Store name  at index 0: " + store_list.get(0).getName());
```

check `store_list` size before accessing it's index.

Comment: Size is 0 which is what I expected considering index 0 was giving an out of bounds exception. Not sure why it's 0, however.

Comment: Check your `serialization` and `deserialization` is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I saw u only store a simple List then you didnt easy way to share data.
 Okey with small data like this : `SparseBooleanArray a = list_view.getCheckedItemPositions();`

I will create class

```
Class A implement Serializable{
   List<String> data;
}
```

then send Serializable via Intent.